# XML - Как использовать фрагменты

Tags: java, android, xml

Как в активити подгружать один из фрагментов?
Имеется три LinearLayout ,каждый из которых содержит несколько элементов, мне необходимо из активити перенести их в фрагменты и из кода вызывать их. У меня вопрос реализации, как это сделать, возможно самым простым примером.. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Способа проще чем любой самый простой туториал по фрагментам вы не найдёте ибо его не существует.

Comment: А можете проинформировать хорошими источниками знаний по фрагментам?

Comment: Ну... В общем-то любая книга по андроиду вышедшая не далее последних 2-3 лет вас вполне устроит.