# Java - Можно ли управлять элементом Include из кода и как?

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть некоторый include вставленный в XML.
Могу ли я управлять элементом `include`?

```
    <include
            android:id="@+id/blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/include_blue_first" />
```

Мне необходимо из кода у данного `include` переопределить его `layout`.

Comment: Тегом include нет, но есть другие варианты. Вам это зачем?

Comment: У меня есть некоторые кнопки-картинки,  вид этих картинок я изобразил в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649890/xml-Как-использовать-фрагменты?noredirect=1 ,как видно на картинке идея такова, что при нажатии на кнопку далее (справа)  определённый LinearLayout изменяет содержимое элементов,  то есть было : "Intro,  1,2,3 ,вперёд" а станет "назад, 4,5,6, вперед". То есть замена содержимого и вот эти файлы замен я храню в отдельных XML файлах в merge.

Comment: Сделайте фон кнопки картинкой, а цифру на ней текстом. И при нажатии кнопки "Далее" меняйте эти цифры.

Comment: Но у кнопки еще должны менятся действия , каждой кнопке соответсвует действие. Я думал просто заменять содержимое инклуда и было  бы счастье.

Comment: В обработчик клика на кнопке просто добавить switch с проверкой текущей цифры на кнопке. Это намного проще и эффективнее, чем способы замены части представления.

Comment: Спасибо,  попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML-файлы макетов служат инструкциями для кодогенератора. В результате его работы  инструкции include уже не будет. Соответственно, изменить её атрибуты в рантайме невозможно. Единственное, что вам может подойти - [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). Но в вашем случае - это костыль. Намного более правильным, простым и эффективным решением было бы изменять на кнопках текст, в обработчике клика проверять его текущее значение и соответственно реагировать.